# lme4: independent variable is a "factor"/ r

Tags: r, panel, lme4

My dependent variable is a factor.
Can I for instance just write: as.numeric(independent_var) ?
I have a panel and my different levels concern time, i.e. years.

```
model <- lmer(independent_var ~ dependent_var1 + (1 + dependent_var1|year), data=data)
```

Or is there another command I should use?
I get a result that has an intercept that is bigger than any factor in the sample.

PS:
My dependent variable is an indication of health. It takes the values 1,2,3,4,5. 5 is best health

Comment: This is technically possible, however your DV is a factor and you may want to use an appropriate method such as ordered/multinomial logit regression. Better you ask that question on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), since it's rather a statistical issue.

Comment: Can you add a little more context?  What does your dependent variable represent, what are typical values?

Answer (score 0):

If `independent_var` is coercible to numeric, then you should use

```
as.numeric(as.character(x))
```

See this example:

```
> x <- as.factor(c(10, 20, 30))
> x
[1] 10 20 30
Levels: 10 20 30
> as.numeric(x)
[1] 1 2 3
> as.numeric(as.character(x))
[1] 10 20 30
```

If you don't coerce to character beforehand, it will coerce factor's levels to numeric, which is what you usually don't want.